# How to re-run method in model rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-geocoder

Im using the `geocoder` gem.  I am looking up zipcodes for addresses.

I have old addresses that I need to run the `:reverse_geocode` method on, but cannot figure out how to re-run the method on older data.  How would I go about doing this?

In other words I want to rerun `:reverse_geocode` on all addresses that do not have zipcode saved.

Comment: You mean, you want to run `reverse_geocode` on all the records that hasn't `zipcode` saved?

Comment: Yes that is a better way of saying it.

Comment: Added the edit to the question.  thank you

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're working on `Address` model:

```
Address.where(zipcode: nil).find_each(&:reverse_geocode)
```

Note that I used [`find_each`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html) instead of `each` because it improves efficiency if you have many records.

Comment: Ok thank you for that.  I ran it in the console no luck though.  Wonder what else I could do

Comment: @ColtonSeal I can't tell you either without wider context.

Comment: yaa, I think ill be able to figure it out.  Thanks for the help.